# Does anyone know the names of schools in 1870/71 London (potentially near Brixton) where wealthy Americans traveling abroad would enroll their sons?

Tags: united-kingdom, education

I am looking for schools in the London area operating in the years 1870/71 at a minimum where Americans traveling at length abroad might have placed their teenage sons to further their education. Specifically schools where the boys could board. I also believe the school I am looking for would have been near or in the Brixton area or perhaps Brixton was part of the name of the school?

Comment: Perhaps the [London International College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_International_College), opened 1867, closed 1889. It had some American students, but it wasn't in Brixton.

Comment: They might have enrolled their sons at Dulwich College, about 3 miles from Brixton. Raymond Chandler was sent there a bit later, around 1900. The school was founded in 1619 and still operates today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [list of *English endowed schools* by county](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_and_Welsh_endowed_schools_(19th_century)) from the early 19th century is organized by county/shire, including [Surrey (location of Brixton)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_and_Welsh_endowed_schools_(19th_century)#Berkshire) and the adjacent [Buckinghamshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_and_Welsh_endowed_schools_(19th_century)#Buckinghamshire) and Middlesex/London counties, which include among others the town of Eton and its eponymous College.

- Surrey:
  -- [Wilson's Grammar School, Camberwwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_School) (Most likely possibility - see below)
  -- [Farnham Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farnham_Grammar_School)
  -- [Royal Grammar School, Guildford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Grammar_School,_Guildford)
  -- [Kingston Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingston_Grammar_School)
  -- [Saint Olave's Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Olave%27s_Grammar_School)
  -- Saint Mary Overey Grammar School
- Berkshire:
  -- [Abingdon Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abingdon_School)
  -- [Childrey Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childrey)
  -- [Newbury Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Bartholomew%27s_School)
  -- [Reading Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_Grammar_School)
  -- [Wallingford Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallingford_Grammar_School)
  -- [Wantage Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Alfred%27s_Academy)
- Buckinghamshire:
  -- [Amersham Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr_Challoner%27s_Grammar_School)
  -- [Aylesbury Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aylesbury_Grammar_School)
  -- [Buckingham Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Royal_Latin_School)
  -- [Eton College](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eton_College)
  -- [Royal Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Grammar_School,_High_Wycombe)
  -- [Marlow Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_William_Borlase%27s_Grammar_School)
- Middlesex (Now wholly incorporated into London County I believe):
  -- [Enfield Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enfield_Grammar_School)
  -- [Hampton Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampton_Grammar_School)
  -- [Harrow grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrow_Grammar_School)
  -- [Highgate Grammar school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highgate_Grammar_School)
- London:
  -- All Hallows Barking Grammar School
  -- [Charterhouse School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charterhouse_School)
  -- [Christ's Hospital School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ%27s_Hospital_School)
  -- [Mercers' Chapel Grammar School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercers%27_Chapel_Grammar_School)
  -- [Merchant Taylors' School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_Taylors%27_School,_Northwood)
  -- [St. Paul's School, London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Paul%27s_School,_London)
  -- [Westminster School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_School)

Wilson's Grammar School was located in Camberwell from founding until 1975. With the centres of Camberwell and Briston barely 2 km apart, that would likely be the school closest to Brixton at the time of interest.

[image]

Counties of South-East England:

[image]

---

Many thanks to the commenters below who assisted in correcting my faulty knowledge of South England geography.

Comment: Brixton is not in or near Berkshire, it is in south London in the Borough of Lambeth.

Comment: @Dave: Hmm! You're correct. Thank you I Looked it up this morning and I'm sure it returned Berkshire - but it seems to have moved into Middlesex over the past few hours. I have corrected.

Comment: Actually Brixton wasn't in Middlesex either - it was in Surrey until 1889 and then in the newly formed County of London.

Comment: @TomH: Ahh! Was the Thames the boundary up to 1889?

Comment: To be technical, the centre of the Thames.

Comment: Yes Middlesex was always entirely on the north side of the Thames.